# Do we have a simple example for DOMPDF?

Tags: dompdf

I downloaded dompdf from : https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
I included the library in my application

```
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'Portrait');
        $dompdf->render();
```

but i got the following error "/php-font-lib/classes/Font.php" is missing

Does anyone know where I can find a simple working example on how to get started with dompdf?

Answer (score 0):

The php-font-lib folder is a link to a different repository: https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib

You should download that too and copy the contents of the src/FontLib folder as a 'classes' subfolder in the php-font-lib directory. Then you'll be able to load the Font class.

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded the source code, which is more for developers. What you want to do is go to the [dompdf releases page](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases) and click on one of the green download buttons (e.g. the one labeled [dompdf-0.6.1.zip](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/download/v0.6.1/dompdf-0.6.1.zip) for the current release). These downloads include all the files you need.

There are other ways of getting dompdf as well. Go to the [Easy Installation](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#easy-installation) section of the read me for more information.